# Extract data from JSON and insert it as new by using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have some database in JSON file, I had already sort and remove some data from object by using ./jq
But I'm stuck at adding new variables in object.
Here is a part of my JSON file:

```
{

    "Name": "Forrest.Gump.1994.MULTi.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.H264-Ao",
    "ID": "SMwIkBoC2blXeWnBa9Hjge9YPs90"

},
{

    "Name": "Point.Blank.2019.MULTi.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.x264-Ao",
    "ID": "OZI4mOuBXuJ7b89FLgXJoozyhHe9"

},
{

    "Name": "The.Incredible.Hulk.2008.MULTi.2160p.UHD.BluRay.REMUX.HDR.HEVC.DTS-HD.MA.7.1",
    "ID": "jZzR4_B_vjm593cYKR7j97XAMv6d"

},
```

Is it possible by using jq and for example RegExp to extract some data and insert it as new variable in object, I wish to achive something like this:

```
{

    "Name": "Forrest.Gump.1994.MULTi.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.H264-Ao",
    "ID": "SMwIkBoC2blXeWnBa9Hjge9YPs90",
    "Year": "1994",
    "Res": "1080p"

},
{

    "Name": "Point.Blank.2019.MULTi.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DDP5.1.x264-Ao",
    "ID": "OZI4mOuBXuJ7b89FLgXJoozyhHe9",
    "Year": "2019",
    "Res": "1080p"

},
{

    "Name": "The.Incredible.Hulk.2008.MULTi.2160p.UHD.BluRay.REMUX.HDR.HEVC.DTS-HD.MA.7.1",
    "ID": "jZzR4_B_vjm593cYKR7j97XAMv6d",
    "Year": "2008",
    "Res": "2160p"

},
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution that assumes for simplicity that the fragment you've shown comes from an array:

```
map( . as $in
     | .Name | capture(".*[.](?<year>[12][0-9]{3})[.](?<rest>.*)")
     | .year as $year
     | (.rest | split(".") | .[1]) as $res
     | $in + {Year: $year, Res: $res} )
```

Hopefully, once you're familiar with some jq basics, such as `map`, `capture`,  and the `EXP as $var` syntax, the above will be more-or-less self-explanatory.

### As a one-liner

Here's the same thing but as a one-liner:

```
map(. + (.Name | capture(".*[.](?<Year>[12][0-9]{3})[.](?<Res>.*)") | {Year, Res: (.Res | split(".")[1])}))
```

Comment: Thank you so much , its works flawlessly. I had already add some more extra parameters based on your solution and everything is running smoothly without any issues.
I appreciate your help :-)